# Iphone How to access camera from UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [access camera from uiwebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915881/access-camera-from-uiwebview)

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;      
picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;      
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;       
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
 return  NO;
```

I am using the above coding but it is not working ..

how to open a camera from webview 
any one help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
UIImagePickerController  *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
[imgPicker release];
```

Below are delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark UIImagePickerController delegate
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *imgCapturePhoto = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: from html page i press the button it came to .m file so there we are using uiwebview so above coding is useful only we are using uiview ..

Comment: see this post i am asking like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915881/access-camera-from-uiwebview       but i am tried that sample i got empty page camera is not opening.. any thoughts?