# ios web view accessing the camera

Tags: ios, swift

Any body have idea, how to access the camera through a web view app in iOS?

Currently using `Xcode 9 swift`. but am willing to change the complete coding, if needed.

At the moment the `WKWebview` is being used.

Refer to this link to see my coding. "[iOS web view application accessing the camera objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018246/ios-web-view-application-accessing-the-camera-objc)"  thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you can open camera on changing url.
when your URL will change below method will call, you can write code for open camera inside function

```
// this is delegate method called while changing url.

(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

//Code for camera after checking url

}
```